# Mvc Checkboxes Bind with model Bool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a mvc model with bool isSelected property. I pass a IEnumerable to my view and return it back to my controller. The issue is that I always get false for checkboxes even if they are checked Here is some code:

Model :

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool selected { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
for(i=0;i<Model.Count();i++) 
{
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.ElementAt(i).selected)
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by this code :  @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.ElementAt(i).selected) ?

Comment: @KrunalPatil Iam trying to bind my selected property from model with the checkbox

Comment: does that mean there are multiple rows that you are passing ?

Comment: yes Iam passing a list of my model, multiple rows are created

Comment: so need some kind of collection like List<> or IList<> to store this, than only you can fetch information of multiple rows, but what i can see here is you are not doing so, and using for loop

Comment: Iam passing the same List of my models to the controller every other attribute is working fine but checkboxes are creating an issue

Comment: so do you mean "User" is the List you are using ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing with this loop is creating multiple elements with the same name (in your case `<input type="checkbox" name="selected" ...>`. Since this is a collection, your name attributes should be `..name="[0].selected..`, `..name="[1].selected..`

If possible change the collection to `IList` so that you can index the names

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.CheckboxFor(m => m[i].selected)
```

Alternatively you can use a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `User` and use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m)
```